# getting offsettop and offsetheight properties does not error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**I am getting option.value properties does not error not sure but I think it is about refs here I am sharing my code please suggest me what I do**

**Code:2**

```
onClick={() => this.change(option.value)}
        key={option.value}
```

**Error Showing: 2**
(parameter) option: OptionsPropType
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts

**Code: 3**

```
<div className="dropdown-label">{current.label}</div>
```

**Error Showing:3**
const current: OptionsPropType | undefined
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts

**DropDown.tsx**

```
import _ from "lodash";
import React, { Component, createRef } from "react";
import DropdownArrow from "../../assets/dropdown-arrow.svg";
import "./Dropdown.scss";

type OptionsPropType = {
  value: number;
  label: string;
};

interface IProps {
  value: any;
  height: number;
  options: Array<OptionsPropType>;
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
}

interface IState {
  isOpen: boolean;
  value: string;
}

export class Dropdown extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  private readonly listRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
  private readonly containerRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;

  constructor(props:IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
      value: props.value
    };
    this.listRef = createRef();
    this.containerRef = createRef();
  }

  change(value:string) {
    this.setState({ value });
    this.props.onChange(value);
    this.close();
  }

  onOutsideClicked = (e?:any) => {
    // only outside clicks allowed
    if (
      this.containerRef.current &&
      this.containerRef.current.contains(e.target)
    ) {
      return;
    }
    document.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.onOutsideClicked);
    this.close();
  };

  toggle() {
    const isOpen = !this.state.isOpen;
    this.setState({ isOpen });
    if (isOpen) {
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.onOutsideClicked);
    }
  }

  close() {
    this.setState({ isOpen: false });
  }

  componentDidRecieveProps(props:any) {
    if (props.value !== this.state.value) {
      this.setState({ value: props.value });
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.listRef.current) {
      const option = this.refs["option-" + this.props.value];
      this.listRef.current.scrollTop =
        option.offsetTop - (this.props.height - option.offsetHeight) / 2;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { value, isOpen } = this.state;
    const current = _.find(this.props.options, (option) => {
      // HACK because select returns string
      return option.value.toString() === value.toString();
    });

    const list = _.map(this.props.options, (option) => (
      <div
        ref={`option-${option.value}`}
        className={`dropdown-option ${
          value.toString() === option.value.toString()
            ? "dropdown-option--selected"
            : ""
        }`}
        onClick={() => this.change(option.value)}
        key={option.value}
      >
        {option.label}
      </div>
    ));

    return (
      <div
        className={`dropdown ${isOpen ? "dropdown--open" : ""}`}
        onClick={() => this.toggle()}
        ref={this.containerRef}
      >
        <div className="dropdown-label">{current.label}</div>
        <div className="dropdown-arrow">
          <img src={DropdownArrow} />
        </div>
        {/* <select onChange={(e) => this.change(e.target.value)} defaultValue={value}>{list}</select> */}
        {isOpen ? (
          <div
            className="dropdown-list"
            style={{ maxHeight: this.props.height + "px" }}
            ref={this.listRef}
          >
            {list}
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Full Project LInk**
https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-night-nqvyy

Comment: This is the part that I didn't fix for you on the last question because it's such a pain in the ass lol.   They set up the code with a ref on each `option` which are `string` refs stored in a dictionary object and they are accessing the ref by looking up its key.  The error is telling you that they need to be updated to newer refs since `string` refs are not supported.  Instead of setting up one ref like we did for the list and the container, we need a `Record` object of refs with one for each option.

Comment: :( Is there any another way ?

Comment: @LindaPaiste   `const option:any = this.refs["option-" + this.props.value];` this solution work fine please give the solution of **code:2 and code:3**